# Google Analytics data changing

Tags: google-analytics

Last week I took sessions and user data from google analytics. This week I look at the same month (January 2019) and the figures are different.

Can anyone explain to me why both are changing?

Ive checked that its 100% of GA sessions and it is so that s why im confused it changes