# Was there a Jan 9 2019 Google analytics change affecting bounce rate?

Tags: google-analytics, bounce-rate

Is there a known change that started at Google between Jan 6 and 9 2019?

I've seen a few posts about this particular date range and the bounce rate on my site changed on that day and has stayed the same since then.

1. https://blog.hudsonfusion.com/google-update-january-2019-analysis
2. [Was Google search ranking algorithm updated on 15 Jan 2019?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/120287/was-google-search-ranking-algorithm-updated-on-15-jan-2019)
3. [Google Analytics data changing](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/125759/google-analytics-data-changing)

[image: GA Bounce rate]

We have observed changes with bounce rates related to JS events we used in the past but between Jan 2019 and today we haven't added anything that should affect that. e.g. previously invoking custom event tracking with GA dropped our bounce rate < 10%.